# Why do my kitchen circuits use a shared neutral circuit with 2 breakers and hot tabs broken?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit

With both breakers tied together, you would lose both circuits if one tripped. It seems a wasted effort.

Comment: Quite a few people found out about MWBC circuits by turning off one breaker and then putting their fingers inside a live box.

Comment: All 3 answers (so far) are 100% correct, and, just to make it abundantly clear, it's also a 100% legal, NEC approved way of wiring circuits.

Answer (score 6):

### Most MWBC's require *common shutoff*, not *common trip*

As it turns out, multi-wire branch circuits generally *don't* (or at least aren't required to) behave as you assume.  This is because while a handle-tied pair of single pole breakers will turn ON and OFF together from the handle (common shutoff), they will *trip* independently from each other.  (This is guaranteed in part by the UL/... requirements for breakers to *trip free*, where holding the handle ON won't stop the breaker from tripping internally.)

This is in contrast to a dryer circuit, (or the occasional oddball MWBC that has both 120V and 240V outlets on it), where a *common trip* two-pole breaker is required. These breakers have an internal linkage between the two halves that guarantees they both trip together.  Panels that use two-pole AFCIs for MWBCs (i.e. older stuff that predates current gen Siemens and MOD 3 GE CAFCIs, as well as Eaton and Square D panels to the best of my knowledge) also generally provide common-trip behavior on AFCI-protected MWBCs, due to limitations of two-pole AFCI breakers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers on this. I have a 1992 house, and I have just upgraded to 200 amps vs 100 amps. When this was done, all the new circuit breakers were common trips.

Comment: Continued from the previous comment. I asked the electrician about the circuit breakers, and he said all shared neutral circuits have to be common trips on new installs now. I live in Los Angeles country.

Comment: @johnchristensen -- I suspect this is a side effect of AFCI requirements (Eaton CH, Eaton BR, and SqD panels require 2-pole AFCIs for shared neutral circuits)

Answer (score 4):

You have found what we call a 'multi wire branch circuit' or MWBC. These require a shared trip for both sides of the circuit. Without that feature, you could end up with a circuit in a dangerous condition.

There are two common benefits to a MWBC.

1. It saves wires vs running two separate circuits.
2. In a kitchen, in particular, it's very handy to have multiple circuits so you can use multiple appliances. If you know things are wired this way, you can use two appliances next to each other everywhere in the kitchen.

Answer (score 4):

> With both breakers tied together, you would lose both circuits if one tripped.

You misunderstand what the handle-ties do. Or rather, do not.

An essential feature of any modern breaker is called **"Trip Free"**.  That is, the breaker will trip even if the handle is held or locked in the "ON" position.  Why would you lock a handle on? It powers a fire alarm, or a university freezer full of important specimens where you don't want custodians turning it off because it's loud. (that happened).

"Trip Free" means a handle-tie would be pretty worthless for **"common trip"**, a code requirement for certain circuits (not yours) to shut off all legs if an overload or short circuit occurs.

When "common trip" is needed, that is provided by an internal mechanism, which can be seen [in breaker tear-downs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQSU6xLkEVI) - on that video it falls out as he separates the halves, and he correctly speculates as to what it is. Yup.

So if two single breakers are tied with a handle-tie, that common trip mechanism is NOT there, and common trip is not guaranteed (but not impossible).

**The purpose of the handle-tie is to protect maintainers working on the circuit**.  The maintainer will reasonably plug a radio into one socket and cut breakers until the radio goes silent.  With either a "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit" (MWBC) or 2 independent circuits serving one receptacle, it is vital for their safety that the maintainer be (forced to) turn off the entire circuit.

It's probably a MWBC, and the purpose there is to save a few bucks on wire.

Comment: I should have read my own question. My kitchen has just one hot. I posed the question because I had read about houses that had such circuits.

Comment: @john wait, they're *NOT*t shared-neutral/MWBC circuits?  Maybe the guy just couldn't physically find 1-pole AFCI breakers because of supply chain issues.